# How to make Symfony multi-entity generic Voter

Tags: php, symfony

I'm implementing voters into my system and I can't figure how to create/extend/implement a more generic way for the voters.

I have the following voter (minified):

```
class EventVoter extends Voter {
    private $roleBaseName = 'ROLE_EVENT';
    private $classname = Event::class;
    private $ownershipMethod = 'getCreatedBy';

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject) {
        // Only vote on {$this->classname} objects
        if (!$subject instanceof $this->classname) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token) {
        // Check if you own this specific entry:
        return $subject->{$this->ownershipMethod} === $user;

    }
}
```

**This one works fine as it is**. However, I also want one for the News, Page, Skill, Foo and Bar.

I could just copy this voter and change the top variables. But as those are the only 3 changes, I want some kind of generic voter which I can load with values e.g. on construct, resulting in a more SOLID code, with the real logic at one spot.

But if I extend Generic class with Voter, it autoloads it. I want it to ignore the generic class, and end up with something like:

```
class EventVoter extends GenericVoter
{
    private $roleBaseName = 'ROLE_EVENT';
    private $classname = Event::class;
    private $ownershipMethod = 'getCreatedBy';

    // Possibly, if required at all:
    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token){
        return parent::voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject,$token)
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I want to check if you can view News and if you can view Event, etc. They all have the same logic to check. Could you write up a quick example about the Entity+interface what you mean? Sounds like something I might want. ANd the abstract class might be too, not sure wether you can extends those like that, but worth a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

Move the `ownershipMethod` logic to an interface and implement it in your Entities, check for that interface in `supports`. You will still need some logic to compute the role.

```
class GenericVoter extends Voter {
    protected function supports($attribute, $subject) {
        if (!$subject instanceof OwnershipInterface) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token) {
        return $subject->getOwnership() === $user;
    }
}

interface OwnershipInterface {
    public function getOwnership();
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Event implements OwnershipInterface {
    public function getOwnership() {
       return $this->getCreatedBy();
    }
}
```

The other one is to declare your `GenericVoter` as `abstract`, so it won't be autoloaded:

```
abstract class GenericVoter extends Voter {
    abstract public function getOwnershipMethod();
    abstract public function getRole();
    abstract public function getClass();

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject) {
        if (!$subject instanceof $this->getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token) {
      return $subject->{$this->getOwnershipMethod()} === $user;
    }
}

class EventVoter extends GenericVoter {
    public function getClass() {
        return Event:class;
    }
    // Implement other abstract functions
}
```

Comment: The first example might be what I'm looking for, especially moving the ownership function to the entity. I'm going to give it a try now :)

Comment: And the  Interface suggestion was exactly what I was looking for. Just one voter which can handle multiple entities, without having to create a voter for each, thanks!